# Use Crystal Report 2010 in Vs 2010 with .Net Framework 3.5  as Target

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I Want Publish My Project with Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5.When I Use Crystal Report 2010 In Vs 2010,To Run The Crystal Report Net 4.0 Is  required But My Target Framework Is 3.5.How Can I Solve This Problem??

Comment: btw - wasn't me that slipped you the -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hosseinsinohe - not sure why the problem. however, a 'solution' to your issue would be to only use the .net 3.5 framework in your vs2010 solution. as you'll be aware, you can set this by going to:

```
project->properties->application->target framework
```

then simply select **.net framework 3.5**

simple :)

Comment: but in your title of the question, you say 'Use Crystal Report 2008 In Vs 2010', hence my answer. thanks for the -1 grrr  :-)

Comment: I am so Sorry for the -1 grrr.Please answer a little edit for Up grrr(My Vote is Locked)